toYaml in helm template inside range causes error converting YAML to JSON
I am tryint to populate my deployment from values and getting error:
YAML parse error on helm-general/templates/deployment.yaml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 46: mapping values are not allowed in this context

My values.yaml
env:
  LIMESURVEY_DB_HOST: 
    value: "host.com"
  LIMESURVEY_DB_PASSWORD: 
    valueFrom:
      secretKeyRef:
        name: limesurvey-pass
        key: pass

deployment.yaml
        env:
          {{- range $k, $v := .Values.env }}
          - name: {{ $k }}
            {{- $v | toYaml | indent 7 }}
          {{- end }}


There's a missing newline in the output.  There's two ways around this.  One is to use the nindent function instead of indent, which also inserts a leading newline
      - name: {{ $k }}
        {{- $v | toYaml | nindent 7 }}

The other takes a little more careful consideration of whitespace.  indent will insert spaces at the start of every line, including the first one, so a line that includes indent shouldn't itself be indented.  You do need the newline before it, so you do not want the Go template - whitespace control marker.  This leads you to
      - name: {{ $k }}
{{ $v | toYaml | indent 7 }}

(The indentation matters, it is not a typo that the second line is not indented.)
Since you're just trying to reproduce an entire block from the values as-is, you also don't need the range loop, which could avoid a little bit of complexity here.
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
        - env:
{{ .Values.env | toYaml | indent 12 }}


(In Helm charts I've written, I've tended towards putting meaningful configuration values and not blocks of raw Kubernetes YAML in the configuration.  For example, I might have limesurvey: { dbHost:, passwordSecret: } configuration and compute the actual env: block in template code.)

Hi Thank you, now I am getting another error: did not find expected key, only if nindent is 7, if it is 6 or 8 then the old one mapping values are not allowed in this context (I have also tried initially with more compact values, and that is why i dont't want to drop my loop, i hope to go back to more consize values, after i solve thisone)

Most Kubernetes YAML files I've seen use 2-space indents, and so 7 is an unusual indentation value.  You should be able to run helm template --debug over your chart and see the output, even if it isn't valid YAML, and this can help debug issues like this.

yes! wrongly calculated indentation! thank you! :)
